# jooq throws NPE when fetchOne is used

Tags: mysql, jooq

I have a simple query on a table which queries with the primary key.

```
            dslContext.select(XXX.NAME)
                .from(XXX)
                .where(
                    XXX.ID.eq(id)
                        .and(XXX.LEVEL.eq(2))
                        .and(XXX.NAME.isNotNull())
                )
                .fetchOne().into(String.class);
```

In my case for a particular id, the query results in a empty set. But jooq seems to throw a NPE. When I further investigated, `fetchOne()` calls `CursorImpl.fetchOne()`. This checks the size of the result and if it is not 1, it returns null. I have a chained `into(String.class)` which gets called on this null value and hence resulting in NPE.

I don't want to call fetch() and iterate over the results/get the first element of the list.

Is there an alternative way of writing the query such that it will throw a `org.jooq.exception.NoDataFoundException` if there is no data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Why a `NullPointerException` is being thrown

Technically, jOOQ doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`. Your calling [`into(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#into-java.lang.Class-) on a potentially `null` record does, as documented also in the Javadoc of [`ResultQuery.fetchOne()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOne--)

> **Returns:**
>   The resulting record or null if the query returns no records.

#### Throwing a `NoDataFoundException`.

You could use [`fetchOptional()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchOptional--) and then use `orElseThrow()`:

```java
String string =
dslContext.select(XXX.NAME)
    .from(XXX)
    .where(
        XXX.ID.eq(id)
            .and(XXX.LEVEL.eq(2))
            .and(XXX.NAME.isNotNull())
    )
    .fetchOptional()
    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoDataFoundException("..."))
    .into(String.class);
```

Note, there's a pending feature request for such a built-in fetch method: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5411

In jOOQ 3.10, you will be able to write:

```java
String string =
dslContext.select(XXX.NAME)
    .from(XXX)
    .where(
        XXX.ID.eq(id)
            .and(XXX.LEVEL.eq(2))
            .and(XXX.NAME.isNotNull())
    )
    .fetchSingle() // Might throw a NoDataFoundException but never returns null
    .into(String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out the NPE was because of me calling `into` like I stated in the question but couldn't find an alternative.